# QPushButton setDown on click

Tags: c++, qt, click, qpushbutton, mousepress

When a `QPushButton` is clicked, I want it to remain pressed down until clicked again.

```
void MainWindow::itemClicked(){

    QPushButton *clickedItem = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(sender());

    qDebug() << clickedItem->isDown();

    if(!clickedItem->isDown())
        clickedItem->setDown(true);
    else
        clickedItem->setDown(false);
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. It will cause the button to be pressed down indefinitely.

`clickedItem->isDown()` is always false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`isDown` always returns false because you are checking it in a slot connected to the `clicked` signal. The `clicked` signal is emited when you press down the push button and release it. So every time the button is pressed and released the clicked signal is emited.

`setCheckable()` would work for you. It will make the button toggle. So when youu click, it'll stay in down state until you click it again.

Answer (score 4):

It should work out of the box using `QAbstractButton::setCheckable(bool)`.

When set to `true` it should act the way you want it to act.

Comment: Thanks, I know about `setCheckable`. I'm wondering why `isDown` doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @МикроПингвин Probably because you do it in a slot which is connected to a `clicked` signal, and the button gets released before the slot is  executed. That is why `isDown` always returns false.

Comment: How would I fix this? Would I need to implement a release slot?

Comment: @МикроПингвин Why bother? Why not just use `QAbstractButton::setCheckable`?

Comment: as @thuga mentioned, why not use a "checkable pushbutton" and if you need the state of the button ask for it using `QAbstractButton::isChecked()`